# How can I effectively sum up matrices in a list (without loop) in R?

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization

Suppose I have a function return 2 matrices. For each input i.

```
f<-function(i){
  m1=matrix(i,ncol=5,nrow=5)
  m2=matrix(i*10,ncol=5,nrow=5)
  r=list(m1=m1,m2=m2)
  return(r)
}
d=lapply(1:3,f)
```

How can I get following 2 things without for loop?

```
d[[1]]$m1+d[[2]]$m1+d[[3]]$m1
d[[1]]$m2+d[[2]]$m2+d[[3]]$m2
```

I tried `sum(lapply(1:3,function(x) (d[[x]]$m1)))` for m1 but does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Reduce`:

```
Reduce("+", lapply(d, function(x) x$m1))
```

You can also get both `m1` and `m2` using `transpose`, `map` and `reduce` from the [purrr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrr/index.html) package:

```
library(purrr)
map(transpose(d), reduce, `+`)
```

This returns:

```
$m1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    6    6    6    6    6
[2,]    6    6    6    6    6
[3,]    6    6    6    6    6
[4,]    6    6    6    6    6
[5,]    6    6    6    6    6

$m2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   60   60   60   60   60
[2,]   60   60   60   60   60
[3,]   60   60   60   60   60
[4,]   60   60   60   60   60
[5,]   60   60   60   60   60
```

Comment: But note that these technically are still loops and `Reduce` is a hidden (byte-compiled) `for` loop. It's not what I consider vectorized (but I would still use alternative 1 myself).

Comment: @Roland vectorized functions use for loops (in C) as well

Comment: Sure, at the C level. The performance difference is whether an R function gets called at each iteration.

Comment: @Roland Oh I understand now. I don't think that's what the OP meant by "without for loops", though, and by that standard I'm not sure what would qualify as vectorized for this problem. (Even an odd solution that combines them into one matrix like `apply(simplify2array(lapply(d, function(x) x$m1)), 1:2, sum)` would have an R function call for every element, much more expensive than one for each matrix)

Comment: I didn't say there is an efficient vectorized alternative. If it was not a nested list, but an array, you could use `rowSums`/`colSums`. But turning this structure into an array would involve copies of the data, which in itself is inefficient. If, however, OP created this object as an array ...

Comment: Could also be written: `Reduce("+", lapply(d, "[[", "m1"))`

Answer (score 2):

We loop through the names of the inner nested `list` elements (`lapply(paste0("m", 1:2), ..`), loop through the `list` elements (`lapply(d, ...`) , extract the elements that matches with the `names` (`d1[[nm]]`) and use `Reduce` with `+` (I did not see the other answer while posting).

```
lapply(paste0("m", 1:2), function(nm) lapply(d, function(d1) Reduce(`+`, d1[[nm]])))
#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    6    6    6    6    6
#[2,]    6    6    6    6    6
#[3,]    6    6    6    6    6
#[4,]    6    6    6    6    6
#[5,]    6    6    6    6    6

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]   60   60   60   60   60
#[2,]   60   60   60   60   60
#[3,]   60   60   60   60   60
#[4,]   60   60   60   60   60
#[5,]   60   60   60   60   60
```

Comment: Thanks !!, this line is too fancy that I am afraid I cannot figure out what's that mean in the future.. Always hard to balance readability and effectiveness.